# Automation of delay effect on couple of items in one container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, settimeout

I have a html code like this :

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a id="b1" href="#"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/redbull/_images/b6.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="b2" href="#"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/redbull/_images/b6.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="b3" href="#"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/redbull/_images/b6.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="b5" href="#"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/redbull/_images/b6.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="b6" href="#"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/redbull/_images/b6.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="b7" href="#"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/redbull/_images/b6.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="b8" href="#"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/redbull/_images/b6.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

and jquery like this one here:

```
    $('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b5, #b6, #b7, #b8, #b9').hide();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b1').fadeIn(500)
    }, 600);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b2').fadeIn(500)
    }, 700);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b3').fadeIn(500)
    }, 800);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b4').fadeIn(500)
    }, 900);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b5').fadeIn(500)
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b6').fadeIn(500)
    }, 1100);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b7').fadeIn(500)
    }, 1200);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b8').fadeIn(500)
    }, 1300);
```

How can I automate the delay for all items in 'buttons' div, so every single next one will appear in delay, but one after another? So instead of writing a setTimeout function for each individual item, do it once, so if I add 100 more items it will still work the same?
The example is here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/5JNyk/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('[id^=b]').hide();
for (var i=1; i<9; i++) {
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#b'+i).fadeIn(500);
     }, 500+100*i);
  })(i);
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/egufag/1/)

Note that you don't *have* do give an id to each `a` element, and you don't have to set the limit in js : you could use a simple class (`<a class=au...`) and do this :

```
$('.au').hide().each(function(i){
  (function(e, i){
    setTimeout(function() {
       e.fadeIn(500);
    }, 500+100*i); 
  })($(this), i);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ahejuf/1/)

Comment: thanks that works great, but is there any way to hide all (b1, b2, b3 etc) buttons using a simple script instead of having this thing here:    $('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b5, #b6, #b7, #b8, #b9').hide(); Also, is there any way of NOT using a number of items, so if i add 3 more items - i won't need to change jquery? just html? I have set i<99 instead of i<9, which will allow me to add up to 98 buttons without changing the jquery, but what about the hide thing I wrote above? new jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/5JNyk/4/